# Python client producing and consuming JMS messages ( HornetQ)

Tags: python, jms, hornetq

I am very suprised that I have not found a solution so far. I have a Python program that needs to use JMS to produce and consume messages. The JMS provider is HornetQ.

I have read about stomp connectors that "may" work with HornetQ. However for various reasons it would be much easier to "just" use JMS as if it was a Java client.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you find something working in python to communicate with Hornetq?

Answer (score 0):

How about the [HornetQ REST Interface](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/hornetq-rest/1.0-beta-1/userguide/html_single/index.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, REST interface may be our fall back strategy . Unfortunately it also means using http for transport and to the best o my knowledge this interface would not work with Hornet discovery groups. So that is why I would consider it a fallback scenario

Comment: Errr... yes... integrating with the discovery groups might be harder than getting basic JMS to work. Could that be an issue for you, even if there was a Stomp option ?

Comment: Yup, even with STOMP it will be the same issue. Bascially I would really need pur JMS or better yet HornetQ core to work in Python somehow- this would be ideal